# How is $L_{2}$ Minkowski norm different from $L^{2}$ norm?

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces

I am reading the book *Multidimensional Particle Swarm Optimization for Machine Learning and Pattern Recognition*.
They use $L_{2}$ *Minkowski norm* (Euclidean) as the distance metric in the feature space for *Long-Term ECG Classification*.

I am myself using just $L^{2}$ seminorm.
I did not find reason why they use Minkowski norm.
Little info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space) what is Minkowski space.

The book Riemann-Finsley Geometry 2005 says that

[image]

The book *The Geometry and Spacetime - An Introduction to Special and General Relavity 2000* says that

> The Minkowski geometry of spacetime as the invariant theory of Lorentz
>   transformations, making constant comparisons with the familiar
>   Euclidean geometry of ordinary space as the invariant theory of
>   rotations.

The Minkowski space has been used in the inverse problem for nonlinear hyperbolic equations.

**What are the advantages of Minkowski norm to $L^{2}$ seminorm when considering ECG classification?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authors of *Multidimensional Particle Swarm" use the ordinary Euclidean metric. They just give it a strange name "$L^2$ Minkowski norm", in my opinion unnecessarily. But it may be common within the subject area.

The  book *Riemann-Finsler Geometry* gives the definition of a related  concept, but it's not the definition the authors of the first book use.  Notice that this is a book from a rather different area of mathematics.

The book *Geometry and Spacetime* is talking about yet different concept.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer!

Answer (score 1):

Minkowskian distance between two vectors $\mathbf{x}_i$ and  $\mathbf{x}_j$ forms the general equation for $L^m$, which is defined as 
\begin{equation}
d(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j)=\biggl( \sum_{k=1}^p (x_{ik}-x_{jk})^m \biggr)^{1/m},
\end{equation}
where $p$ is the number of features.
The Euclidean and Manhattan distance are simply special cases of the $L^1$ and $L^2$ distance, respectively.

Quite basically, you can use almost any distance metric you want for the fitness function.  For example, the dot product: $\mathbf{x}_i^T\mathbf{x}_j$, polynomial kernels such as $K(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j)=(1+\mathbf{x}_i^T\mathbf{x}_j)^d$, or radial basis kernels: 
$K(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j)=\exp[-d(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j)]$.

Minkowski is merely a general family of distances, and when working with metaheuristics such as PSO it is better to evaluate different distance metrics for their informativeness in class prediction (classification).

Comment: No, Manhattan is L1 and Euclidean is L2, change the order.