# Quadratic Time-Frequency Representation with L2 norm

Tags: normed-spaces, distribution-theory, time-series

I have been reading the book *Multidimensional Particle Swarm Optimization for Machine Learning and Pattern Recognition*.
They use different norm for different problems in their automatic ECG detection system. 
Therefore, they select a general class of norms **l2 Minkowski norm**, but they do not use Poincare group, instead [Euclidean group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618090/how-is-l-2-minkowski-norm-different-from-l2-norm).

The book does not specify exact groups for the system.
The broad variability of norms suggests me a weakness in the selection of groups.
They do not also specify the TFR, but I believe some of it is based on Wigner-Ville distribution with one integral.

**How do you need different norms for different problems in automatic detection system of ECG?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from my professor that you can use Minkowskian space without the selection of specific group like Poincare.